prismaで型定義を行うためにmoduleを呼び出すと読み込みされなくなる
下記のようにPrismaをimportして使用しています。
import { Prisma } from "@prisma/client";

export const CreateForm = () => {
  const { register } = useForm<Prisma.UserCreateInput>({
    defaultValues: {
      email: "",
      name: "",
    },
  });

shemaに定義はされてあるので存在はある

実際に呼び出すと読み込みに一時ほどかかる

